# If $H$ is a Hopf algebra, do we have $H^{cop}$ is a Hopf algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, hopf-algebras, quantum-groups, coalgebras, nichols-algebras

Let $H=(H, m, u, \Delta, \epsilon, S)$ be a Hopf algebra, see for example [the lecture notes](http://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/~kab/Hopf%20lects%201-8.pdf), where $m$ is the multiplication, $u$ is the unit, $\Delta$ is the comultiplication, $\epsilon$ is the counit, $S$ is the antipode. Let $H^{cop} = (H, m, u, \Delta^{op}, \epsilon, S)$, where $m,u,\epsilon,S$ are the same maps as the maps in $H$, and $\Delta^{op}=\tau \circ \Delta$, $\tau$ is the flip map. Is $H^{cop}$ a Hopf algebra?

I am asking this question because in the book: [Hopf algebras and their actions on rings](http://bookstore.ams.org/cbms-82/), pages 213, 214, it is said that $t_{M,N}$ is a braiding if $H^{cop}$ is a Hopf algebra. Why the condition is not "$H$ is a Hopf algebra" but "$H^{cop}$ is a Hopf algebra"? Are "$H$ is a Hopf algebra " and "$H^{cop}$ is a Hopf algebra" equivalent? Thank you very much.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a Hopf algebra $H$, $H^{cop}$ may or may **not** be a Hopf algebra. **If it is**, then the maps $t_{M,N}$ above define a braiding.

Comment: thank you very much. Where do we use the condition $H^{cop}$ is a Hopf algebra? In the book, it is only assumed that $H$ is a bialgebra. According to [the lecture notes](http://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/~kab/Hopf%20lects%201-8.pdf), $H$ is a bialgebra implies that $H^{cop}$ is a bialgebra.

Comment: But isn't $H^{cop}$ always a Hopf algebra? For example $(S\otimes id)\circ\Delta^{op}=(id\otimes S)\circ\Delta$, right? Where does the definition of Hopf algebra fail for $\Delta^{op}$?

Comment: @freakish Why equal? the first is $S(c_2)\otimes c_1$ and the second is $c_1\otimes S(c_2)$

Comment: @DavidHill, but in the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yetter%E2%80%93Drinfeld_category), the condition "$H^{cop}$ is a Hopf algebra" is not required?

Comment: I'm a bit suspicious. Note that the compatibility condition in the wiki page is different than (10.6.11) above. It may be that the condition on the wiki page automatically implies that $H^{cop}$ is a Hopf algebra.

Comment: @David, thank you very much.

Comment: @DavidHill, I do the following computations. It seems that the condition $H^{cop}$ is a Hopf algebra is not used. Let $u, v, w \in V $. Then (here $\Psi_{V,V}$ is $t_{V,V}$)

Comment: \begin{align}
& \Psi_{12} \Psi_{23} \Psi_{12} (u \otimes v \otimes w) \\
& =  \Psi_{12} \Psi_{23}(  (u_{(-1)}.v) \otimes u_{(0)} \otimes w ) \\
& =  \Psi_{12}  (  (u_{(-1)}.v) \otimes (u_{(0)})_{(-1)}.w \otimes (u_{(0)})_{(0)} ) \\
& =  ( u_{(-1)}.v )_{(-1)}.( ( (u_{(0)})_{(-1)} ).w ) \otimes (u_{(-1)}.v)_{(0)} \otimes ( u_{(0)} )_{(0)}  \\
& =  ( (u_{(-1)})_{(1)}.v )_{(-1)}.(  (u_{(-1)})_{(2)}.w ) \otimes ((u_{(-1)})_{(1)}.v)_{(0)} \otimes u_{(0)} \\
& =  ( ((u_{(-1)})_{(1)}.v )_{(-1)} (u_{(-1)})_{(2)} ).w \otimes ((u_{(-1)})_{(1)}.v)_{(0)} \otimes u_{(0)}, 
\end{align}

Comment: \begin{align}
& \Psi_{23} \Psi_{12} \Psi_{23} (u \otimes v \otimes w) \\
& = \Psi_{23} \Psi_{12} (u \otimes v_{(-1)}.w \otimes v_{(0)}) \\
& = \Psi_{23} ((u_{(-1)}v_{(-1)}).w \otimes u_{(0)} \otimes v_{(0)}) \\
& = (u_{(-1)} v_{(-1)}).w \otimes (u_{(0)})_{(-1)}.v_{(0)} \otimes ( u_{(0)} )_{(0)} \\
& = ( (u_{(-1)})_{(1)} v_{(-1)}).w \otimes (u_{(-1)})_{(2)}.v_{(0)} \otimes u_{(0)}.      
\end{align}

Comment: Therefore the Yetter-Drinfeld condition 
\begin{align}
& (h_{(1)}.v )_{(-1)}   h_{(2)} \otimes (h_{(1)}.v)_{(0)}\\
& = h_{(1)} v_{(-1)} \otimes h_{(2)}.v_{(0)}.
\end{align}
implies that (every $u_{(-1)}$ is some $h \in H$)
\begin{align}
& ((u_{(-1)})_{(1)}.v )_{(-1)} (u_{(-1)})_{(2)} \otimes ((u_{(-1)})_{(1)}.v)_{(0)} \otimes u_{(0)} \\
& = (u_{(-1)})_{(1)} v_{(-1)} \otimes (u_{(-1)})_{(2)}.v_{(0)} \otimes u_{(0)}.
\end{align}
Therefore
\begin{align}
& \Psi_{12} \Psi_{23} \Psi_{12} (u \otimes v \otimes w) = \Psi_{23} \Psi_{12} \Psi_{23} (u \otimes v \otimes w).
\end{align}

Comment: @DavidHill, I found [a paper](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0022404993901149/1-s2.0-0022404993901149-main.pdf?_tid=7ca2e834-00fd-11e7-8ee1-00000aacb362&acdnat=1488647617_d962db56f419b6c11e6d2976389bd6ae). According to Proposition 3 of this paper, the condition $H^{cop}$ is a Hopf algebra is only used to prove that $t_{M,N}$ is invertible.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is generally no.
The conditions: "$H$ is a Hopf algebra" and "$H^{cop}$ is a Hopf algebra" are generally not equivalent. But they are, if we confine ourselves at the bialgebra level. To be more detailed:

If $H=(H, m, u, \Delta, \epsilon)$ is a bialgebra, $H^{cop} = (H, m, u, \Delta^{op}, \epsilon)$ is also a bialgebra called **co-opposite bialgebra**. (and $H^{op} = (H, m^{op}, u, \Delta, \epsilon)$ is called the **opposite bialgebra**).

However, if $H=(H, m, u, \Delta, \epsilon, S)$ is a hopf algebra, $(H, m, u, \Delta^{op}, \epsilon, S)$ is not necessarily a hopf algebra. (Neither is $(H, m^{op}, u, \Delta, \epsilon, S)$).

A sufficient condition is **the antipode to be invertible**: If $H=(H, m, u, \Delta, \epsilon, S)$ is a hopf algebra with invertible (i.e.: bijective) antipode then $H^{cop} = (H, m, u, \Delta^{op}, \epsilon, S^{-1})$ is also a hopf algebra. (and $H^{op} = (H, m^{op}, u, \Delta, \epsilon, S^{-1})$ as well). 
These are now called the co-opposite and the opposite Hopf algebras respectively.
Now, if $S^2=Id$ thus $S=S^{-1}$, then the co-opposite $H^{cop} = (H, m, u, \Delta^{op}, \epsilon, S)$ and the opposi-te $H^{op} = (H, m^{op}, u, \Delta, \epsilon, S)$ are also hopf algebras. For example, this is the situation for either commutative or cocommutative hopf algebras.
(see also: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1691054/195021 for a related discussion).